# Failed to load resource with bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Tags: javascript, bundle, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with bootstrap. I imported the script in node_modules with the npm manager and it worked when I opened in my live server, but when a tried to deploy in vercel this error popped up:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1

And the funcionalities of bs components didn´t work.

I tried to set the script on the header and the end of the body. Then I tried with the others js archives, like bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, etc, etc. None of those works.
I´m new in programming and I only did projects on frontend, so I´m pretty sure m missing something important. If anyone is so kind as to help I would appreciate it.

I describe what I tried in the problem. All had been working well until I deployed in vercel and popped up that error.

This is the repository: https://github.com/MaximilianoLeonel23/menu_cafeteria

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Start by showing us your actual implementation code.

Comment: it would be really useful if we could see your code.  The most common problem here is that you are looking for it in the wrong path.    Your include should probably look similar to this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: I just add the link to the github